# Error while running jar file

Tags: java, hadoop

I used Ubuntu 18.04.4 in my IBM virtual machine and I got an error while running my jar file in Ubuntu terminal. I've already installed Java.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ProgramDriver
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

Comment: Which Java version have you installed and how? Does the Jar work on other systems? Have you configured Hadoop?

Comment: That looks more like a improperly coded Java File.

Comment: @Kulfy i installed java using terminal and this is my java version  "openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04, mixed mode, sharing)"

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is missing of a library. When you Java program start it load the JVM (java virtual machine) and after that it start to load also the necessary libraries to work with.

You have error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` which mean that the class is missing and the class is: `org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver`. So from this error you can see that the missing class is inside `Apache Hadoop`. The is the home page for this project: https://hadoop.apache.org/

What you should do? 
If you are author of the program which you intend to work with then add this dependency somehow to you program. You can add it inside the jar or outside with relative path or absolute path.

If you can not change the code then check the documentation of the project which you are using. See if there is something about including additional libraries and you can also check `Apache Hadoop` for example how to be used and installed.

If all of this does not help you can also check how you can add additional libraries inside the JVM but then every time when you start this JVM no matter for which project you will have `Apache Hadoop` inside and maybe is not the optimal solution.

Best luck to all!